# How to use WHM API's from external server

Tags: whm

I have my server "A" running on ruby on rails.
My hosting server "B" has WHM installed on it.

How can I use WHM's APIs to get some data about hosting server.

For example I want to list all the domains and sub domains per user.

Is it possible? if yes then how?

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the WHM API documentation:

> https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+WHM+API+1

To use the WHM API, you need to understand the following first:

> https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Use+WHM+API+to+Call+cPanel+API+and+UAPI

---

To list all usernames and domains on your server: (optional search parameters)

> https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/WHM+API+1+Functions+-+listaccts

The following call will list all your accounts and their details:

```
https://hostname.example.com:2087/cpsess##########/json-api/listaccts?api.version=1
```

Example response to expect from the above call:

```
{
  "data": {
    "acct": [
      {
        "mailbox_format":"mdbox"
        "inodesused":"1",
        "inodeslimit":"unlimited",
        "maxaddons": "1",
        "ip": "192.168.0.20",
        "ipv6": ["0101:ca75:0101:ca75:0101:ca75:0101:ca77"],
        "outgoing_mail_suspended": 0,
        "outgoing_mail_hold": 0,
        "min_defer_fail_to_trigger_protection": 5,
        "legacy_backup": 0,
        "diskused": "0M",
        "maxftp": "2",
        "startdate": "13 Jul 08 14:33",
        "max_defer_fail_percentage": "10",
        "disklimit": "100M",
        "is_locked": "0",
        "suspendtime": null,
        "email": "",
        "domain": "example.com",
        "unix_startdate": 1373312011,
        "user": "example",
        "plan": "plan9",
        "shell": "\/bin\/bash",
        "maxpop": "20",
        "backup": 0,
        "theme": "paper_lantern",
        "owner": "root",
        "max_email_per_hour": "100",
        "suspendreason": "not suspended",
        "maxlst": "5",
        "suspended": 0,
        "maxsql": "1",
        "maxparked": "1",
        "partition": "home",
        "maxsub": "5"
      },
    ]
  },
  "metadata": {
    "version": 1,
    "reason": "OK",
    "result": 1,
    "command": "listaccts"
  }
}
```

---

But to list sub-domains, you would need to use the cPanel API.

> https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+SubDomain%3A%3Alistsubdomains

After you got the domains and usernames, you can use the username to get it's sub-domains: *Replace `[USERNAME_HERE]` with the cPanel username.*

```
https://hostname.example.com:2087/cpsess###########/json-api/cpanel?cpanel_jsonapi_user=[USERNAME_HERE]&cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion=2&cpanel_jsonapi_module=SubDomain&cpanel_jsonapi_func=listsubdomains
```

Example response to expect from the above call:

```
{
  "cpanelresult": {
    "apiversion": 2,
    "func": "listsubdomains",
    "data": [
      {
        "domainkey": "subdomain_example.com",
        "rootdomain": "example.com",
        "status": "not redirected",
        "subdomain": "subdomain",
        "reldir": "home:public_html\/subdomain",
        "basedir": "public_html\/subdomain",
        "dir": "\/home\/example\/public_html\/subdomain",
        "domain": "subdomain.example.com"
        "web_subdomain_aliases": "1"
      }
    ],
    "event": {
      "result": 1
    },
    "module": "SubDomain"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you vote up my question ?

Comment: Sure, hope I helped :) enjoy!

Comment: you sure did. Thanks